Why did my caulk tube stop dispensing halfway through?
I just purchased a new tube of Mapei caulk. I used it to caulk a good portion of my bathroom and then all of sudden, no more caulk would come out of the tube. It's not the caulking gun. Can someone tell me what's going on and how to fix it? I got halfway through the tube and now nothing. When I shove a wire down the top and all the way to the bottom of the tube, the wire comes out with fresh caulk, so I know the tube isn't dry.

Common to sometimes have an air pocket.  Continue to pull the trigger on the caulking gun. If there is caulk in the tube and the gun is advancing the plunger, the remaining caulk  will come out.

Take the tube out and check for kinks.  Put it back in turned 90 or 180 degrees for a bit.  Unless a new gun, it might be slipping at that section.  Place something between the back of tube and gun ram.

Thanks for the great feedback. What worked for me was turning the tube as suggested by @crip659. Finished the job this morning! I've never had that happen before!

I've encountered all manner of issues with caulk tubes, from air pockets acting as springs, to tube bursts, to spoiled caulk. Never this one, at least with a supposedly fresh tube.
My best guess is that the tube has a flaw in it blocking progress of the plunger. Either that or there's a hardened plate of caulk up one side or something.
Bottom line: Doesn't matter what we say. You're done with that one unless you pull it apart and investigate. Or just get another.

I'm with this answer (tube wall flaw) but if you really want to scrape the bottom of the pot -- maybe the tube's inner seal (the one you break with the long pin) has a hardened gob of caulk blocking it, and your wire trick pushes it out of the way but then like a flap it reseals the nozzle.   IDK how you'd fix that without destroying the nozzle.  Maybe with a little fishing hook?
